# MacBook Pro 2019 can't boot live USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, live-usb, macbook

I downloaded Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS and put it on a USB flash drive. Rebooted the MacBook into recovery mode (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) and enabled booting of external media and unsigned operating systems. Rebooted again holding <kbd>Option</kbd> and selected to boot from my USB drive ("EFI Boot" in the boot menu).

The Ubuntu boot menu (GNU GRUB version 2.02) shows up, but no matter what I choose in the menu, it just goes into a kernel panic with a lot of ACPI related errors, including this one:

```
ERROR: Unable to locate IOAPIC for GSI 34
```

[image]

System information:

MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2019, Two Thunderbolt 3 ports)

- Processor: 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5
- Memory: 16 GB 2133 MHz LPDDR3
- Graphics: Intel Iris Plus Graphics 645 1536 MB
- macOS Catalina (version 10.15.1)

Comment: This only appears to be a problem with computers that have been upgraded to Catalina. My guess is that there was a bundled UEFI update that is to blame.

Comment: I too have the same problem. Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: Check out https://t2linux.org/

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and was able to pass that step by adding `noapic` or `acpi=strict` (more lax approach to ACPI from kernel) to the GRUB boot loader line:

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz [...] quiet splash noapic ---
```

But after this, the boot gets stuck on another kernel panic related to EFI. This you can bypass if you tell the kernel to not start the EFI runtime -strongly not recommended:

```
linux /casper/vmlinuz [...] quiet splash noapic efi=noruntime ---
```

But the boot doesn't complete and probably your mac will reboot without finalizing the full boot process.