# Ubuntu 20.04 on MacbookAir 2019/EFIBoot live not launching_Rebooting

Tags: boot, system-installation, live-usb, macbook, 20.04

**I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04 as the only OS on a MacbookAir released on 2019 (MacbookAir8,1) with MacOS Mojave (10.14) preinstalled and it seems that I have a graphic issue during live session launching**

I went through the following steps:

1. Create a Ubuntu bootable USB stick with the dedicated software on Ubuntu
2. Boot MacOS in recovery mode and turned the Secure Boot to "No Security" and allowed "Booting from external media" (See. picture 1)
3. Boot Macbook and chosed the 2nd external drive in EFI Mode (See. picture 2).
   In my previous test, I selected the 1st external drive in EFI Mode and resulted in the following error message : "a software update is required to use this startup disk"
4. An error message quickly appeard finishing in "error: file '/boot/' not found" (Se. picture 3).
5. After that, the followin GRUB launching option apperead :
   Ubuntu
   Ubuntu (safe graphics)
   OEM install
   Boot from the next volume
   UEFI Firmware Settings
   (See. picture 4)
   I was surprised not to see the option "Try Ubuntu without installing".
6. In either of the booting option I chose, I got many lines appearing on the screen (See. picture 5) and then the Macbook rebooted normally on MacOS without launching the Ubuntu installation screen.

If I choose, "Ubuntu", I have the following last lines:

`thunderbolt 0000:05:00.0: ICM firmware is in wrong mode: 15
xhci_hcd 0000:06:00.0: xHCI host controller not responding, assume dead
xhci_hcd 0000:06:00.0: HC died; cleaning up`

If I choose "Ubuntu (safe graphics),I have the following last lines in addition :

`clocksource: tsc: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2f75b1eac7a, max_idle_ns: 440795210882 ns
clocksource: Switched to clocksource tsc`

[Screen captures of the installation process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L64yi.jpg)

I also tried the following solution with no results : [MacBook Pro 2019 can't boot live USB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1185203/macbook-pro-2019-cant-boot-live-usb/1186229#1186229)

**I tried live session with Ubuntu 18.04 instead of 20.04 and used the safe graphics mode "nomodeset" and the live session is launching but the keyboard and mouse are not working.
I tried pluging an external mouse through the USB-Thunderbolt adapter but it is not working either.**

Thank you a lot for your help.
Be safe,

Jay

Comment: Additionnay, the installation of REFIND did not solve the problem, when clicking on Ubuntu in the GRUB panel, I still got many lines appearing on a black screen (See. picture 5) and then the Macbook rebooted normally on MacOS without launching the Ubuntu installation screen.

Comment: Check out https://t2linux.org/

Answer (score 0):

After many researches, as of now, I only see 2 options to install Ubuntu on Macbook released after 2016 (notably mine MacbookAir8,1):

1) Install Ubuntu 18.04 by following the advices from this useful page :
[https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7](https://gist.github.com/roadrunner2/1289542a748d9a104e7baec6a92f9cd7])
2) Try to install 20.04 but sorry it seems not be an option for now, no solution find for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This gist link is dead.